# Как правильно совместить два метода?

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

Есть 2 метода:

```
string GetStringDataFromDataRow(DataRow dr, string key)
{
   //... код
}

int GetIntegerDataFromDataRow(DataRow dr, string key)
{
   //... код
}
```

Оба они делают одно и тоже - из DataRow по имени колонки выбирают данные.
**Можно ли их как-то совместить в один метод?**

Я вижу только один способ - сделать один метод GetDataFromDataRow, который возвращает String, а на месте потом ее конвертить в int.

Есть ли другой способ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно сделать [Generic(шаблонный) метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
T GetDataFromDataRow<T>(DataRow dr, string key)
{
    //... код
}
```

В этом случае, ожидаемый тип возвращаемого значения указывается непосредственно при вызове метода:

```
string stringData = GetDataFromDataRow<string>(dr, key);
int integerData = GetDataFromDataRow<int>(dr, key);
```

Answer (score 0):

А чем Вас стандартные варианты не устраивают?

Для таблицы:

```
DataTable dt;
string data = dt.Rows[rowNumber][colName].ToString();
```

Для строки:

```
DataRow dr;
string data = dr[colName].ToString();
```